# Graph-coloring model

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

There are 12 cruise ships scheduled to be in a port for various days during a

given week. The ships must be assigned to one of five different piers (only one

ship at a time can be docked at a pier). The question is whether an assignment

of ships to piers is possible, given ships’ visiting plans. Describe how to make

a graph-coloring model of this assignment problem: What are the vertices, what

are the edges, what are the colors?

Is 
Vertices = ships,  edges = overlapping visit,  colors = piers  correct ? 
otherwise help me solve this.

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Thanks @saulspatz  for confirmation.